# Can't get paste event to work in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this Typescript code:

```
const pasteFn = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
    const { clipboardData } = e;
    const text = clipboardData?.getData('text/plain');
    console.log(text);
};

window.addEventListener('paste', pasteFn);
```

I've searched like crazy and tried all examples, but I don't understand the error I get:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: keyof WindowEventMap, listener: (this: Window, ev: Event | DeviceMotionEvent | DeviceOrientationEvent | GamepadEvent | ... 23 more ... | StorageEvent) => any, options?: boolean | ... 1 more ... | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"paste"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof WindowEventMap'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: ClipboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(e: ClipboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Property 'clipboardData' is missing in type 'Event' but required in type 'ClipboardEvent'.ts(2769)
lib.dom.d.ts(3747, 14): 'clipboardData' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 7):

The paste event is available on the document, not on the Window.
Use:

```ts
window.document.addEventListener('paste', pasteFn);
```

`paste` is defined in interface `DocumentAndElementEventHandlersEventMap`:

```ts
interface DocumentAndElementEventHandlersEventMap {
    "copy": ClipboardEvent;
    "cut": ClipboardEvent;
    "paste": ClipboardEvent;
}
```

This interface is extended by `HTMLElementEventMap` and `DocumentEventMap`, and not by `WindowEventMap`

Comment: You're right, but when we decieve typescript with something like this : `window.addEventListener('paste',(e) => pasteFn((e as any) as ClipboardEvent));`, javascript at runtime gives no error and the paste event listener callback function has ben added and works correctly. Is it a mistake in typing logic of the `window` object?

Comment: Also when `strictNullChecks` in tsconfig is `false`, `window.addEventListener('paste', pasteFn);` has no error and javascript works fine.

Comment: @mahooresorkh 1. Valid remark. The event bubbles up to Window, thus the variant with cast to any works. Is it an error  in lib.dom typings? I guess you can argue 2 ways - on one hand TS should map allowed operations from JS, on the other it perhaps conceptually makes sense to paste onto some element on the page. 2. I tried to reproduce on typescript playground, still get the same error.